# how to save output of if elif statement to new variable in python dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

how do i edit the following script to save the outputs as new variables in the original dataframe?

AKA: instead of the print function, have the output be saved as a new variable for each if elif statement?

```
import re

df = pd.read_excel('edmundstest.xlsx')

for Keyword, Landing_Page in zip(df["Keyword"], df["Landing_Page"]):

# the url
    if "/2019/" in Landing_Page:
        new_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page
        print(f"new_model_core_incentives {new_model_core_incentives}")
    elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", Landing_Page):
        used_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page 
        print(f"used_model_core_incentives {used_model_core_incentives}")    

# the "keywords"
    if "2019" in Keyword:
        new_word = Keyword
        print(f"new_word {new_word}")
    elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", Keyword) is None:
        old_word = Keyword
        print(f"old_word {old_word}")
```

i.e., : `new_model_core_incentives` or `used_model_core_incentives` as a new variable in the dataframe and `new_word` and `old_word` as a new variable in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary:

```
dict[Keyword]=f"new_model_core_incentives {new_model_core_incentives}"
dict2[Keyword]=f"old_word {old_word}"
```

Something like this:

```
import re

df = pd.read_excel('edmundstest.xlsx')

dict, dict2 = {}, {}

for Keyword, Landing_Page in zip(df["Keyword"], df["Landing_Page"]):

# the url
    if "/2019/" in Landing_Page:
        new_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page
        print(f"new_model_core_incentives {new_model_core_incentives}")
    elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", Landing_Page):
        used_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page 
        dict[Keyword]=f"new_model_core_incentives {new_model_core_incentives}"    

# the "keywords"
    if "2019" in Keyword:
        new_word = Keyword
        print(f"new_word {new_word}")
    elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", Keyword) is None:
        old_word = Keyword
        dict2[Keyword]=f"old_word {old_word}"
```

Comment: would I put that where the print statement is?

Comment: yeah. just make sure to predefine the dict

Comment: is there a way to do this to the original df?

Comment: I don't know the structure of the dataframe. If it's a mutable object you can always just append to it